# Inserting a Label inside the CollectionView every time a property changes inside the objects

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a `CollectionView` with `DateTime` objects inside it. I would like to insert a `Label` inside the `CollectionView` (probably using grouping, I think that's the right way) whenever scrolling through the `CollectionView` I find an element where the `DateTime.Month` property has changed

```
<CollectionView
    HeightRequest="45">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
                      <Label  Text="{Binding Month}" FontSize="7" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                 </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
         </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
 </CollectionView>
```

UPDATE:

**in c#:**

```
public class HumorGroup : ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>
        {
            public string Name { get; private set; }

            public HumorGroup(string name, ObservableCollection<HumorDiary> icon) : base(icon)
            {
                Name = name;
            }
        }

public ObservableCollection<HumorGroup> TotHumor { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<HumorGroup>();

int count = 0;
foreach(HumorDiary hd in PagineDiario)
        {
            if(hd.Dt.Date.Month!= count)
            {
                count = hd.Dt.Date.Month;
                TotHumor.Add(new HumorGroup(hd.Dt.Date.Month.ToString(), new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>
                {
                        
                 }));
             }               
        }
```

I tried but I don't think I understand the logic. In my test I check that the `Month` property is different, if so, I create a new group, but when the If control is true, I would like to add all the elements within that group, while as I did it doesn't. how could i solve?

Comment: do you want to group your data by month?

Comment: exactly, is that possible? the various elements that populate the collectionView are in a SqLite database

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping

Comment: I have updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a new group when the month changes

```
   int month = 0;
   HumorGroup group = null;

   foreach(HumorDiary hd in PagineDiario)
    {

        if(group == null || hd.Dt.Date.Month != count)
        {
            if (group != null) TotHumor.Add(group);

            // create a new group
            count = hd.Dt.Date.Month;
            group = new HumorGroup(count.ToString(), new ObservableCollection<HumorDiary>();
        }

        group.Add(hd);
    }
```

Comment: `if (group! = null) TotHumor.Add (group);` I will have to enter this string after creating the group, not before, right? After that `HumorGroup` I will have to declare it again as null, otherwise at every foreach check it will enter me inside the if loop, or am I wrong? Thank you

Comment: I don't think so, that should only be true the very first time through the loop